# Is there a way to publish a ROS AnyMsg in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros

I am trying to publish a rospy.msg.AnyMsg by doing the following:

```
import rospy
.
.
.
publisher = rospy.Publisher('jason_topic',
                            rospy.msg.AnyMsg,
                            queue_size=10)

publisher.publish(ros_message)
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subscriber_any.py", line 26, in <module>
    publisher.publish(ros_message)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 879, in publish
    data = args_kwds_to_message(self.data_class, args, kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 118, in args_kwds_to_message
    if len(data_class._slot_types) == 0:
AttributeError: type object 'AnyMsg' has no attribute '_slot_types'
```

I did a `print(dir(rospy.msg.AnyMsg()))` and verified that there was no attribute _slot_types. Is what I am trying to do possible and if so how?

Comment: No, you cannot use `AnyMsg` in this way. The question, though, is *why* are you trying to use it this way? There really shouldn't be a situation where this is desirable.

Comment: I am trying to create a bridge where ROS messages can pass through.

Comment: If you already know the topic names you should be dynamically getting their types as registered with the core and creating publishers that way.

Comment: I am trying to do it without knowing the topic names.

Comment: Then you'll still need to get a list of topics and their types that are registered with the core. You can't create a publisher or subscriber without a topic name/type

Comment: Yes I thought I could get them dynamically somehow from the AnyMsg but it appears I cannot. I would have to know them as you said to subscribe to get the AnyMsg to begin with.